# Trying to get the 5 most collinear points out of multiple points gives wrong result when rotating the points

Tags: python, math

Let's say I have a list of 15 different points with x and y coordinates. How can I find the 5 most collinear points? They don't need to be perfectly collinear but they should reliably be the most collinear points of all possible combinations.

My current approach:

1. Get all possible combinations using itertools.combinations
2. Iterate over every combination of 5 points
3. Calculate the slope from first point to every other point
4. Calculate the absolute differences between the first slope and all other slopes
5. Sum up all differences
6. Compare the sums of all combinations and return the combination with the smallest sum

This works sometimes but sometimes also returns garbage.

Here is an example:

The algorithm works with the `points_0deg` list. If I take the same points and rotate them 80 degrees (`points_80deg`) the red points are found to be the most collinear instead of the green points.

[image]

```
import itertools

points_0deg = [[818.5, 395.5], [688.5, 586.5], [556.5, 448.5], [819.5, 779.5], [657.5, 892.5], [558.5, 727.5],
               [658.5, 278.5], [453.5, 279.5], [426.5, 588.5], [877.5, 589.5], [458.5, 893.5], [301.5, 403.5],
               [296.5, 774.5], [241.5, 583.5], [558.5, 585.5]]
points_80deg = [[498.5, 397.5], [665.5, 558.5], [505.5, 665.5], [356.5, 533.5], [781.5, 711.5], [876.5, 463.5],
                [958.5, 641.5], [619.5, 816.5], [700.5, 373.5], [925.5, 838.5], [414.5, 906.5], [322.5, 737.5],
                [580.5, 998.5], [776.5, 975.5], [640.5, 687.5]]


def check_collinear(points):
    x1, y1 = points[0]

    slope = []
    for point in points[1:]:
        x, y = point
        slope.append((y - y1) / (x - x1) if (x - x1) != 0 else float('inf'))

    diff = []
    for val in slope[1:]:
        diff.append(abs(slope[0] - val))

    return sum(diff)


def find_most_collinear(points):
    combinations = list(itertools.combinations(points, 5))
    collinear_points = None
    min_sum = float('inf')
    for comb in combinations:
        s = check_collinear(comb)
        if s <= min_sum:
            min_sum = s
            collinear_points = comb
    return collinear_points


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(find_most_collinear(points_0deg))
    print(find_most_collinear(points_80deg))
```

Comment: Your points seem to be 2 concentric circles centred on (640,690) - is that a coincidence or is it always the case? Is there some requirement for this *"centre"* to be one of the 5 points?

Comment: That will pretty much always be the case. Usually the center point should be one of the 5 points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple algorithm is to find the two extreme points of the set (find the average M, then the point A most distant from M and then the point B most distant from A).
Then as score use the sum of squared distances from the line passing through A and B. In code:

```
# gg is the candidate group
avg = ((sum(x for x, y in gg)/5), (sum(y for x, y in gg)/5))
ax, ay = max(gg, key=lambda p:(p[0]-avg[0])**2 + (p[1]-avg[1])**2)
bx, by = max(gg, key=lambda p:(p[0]-ax)**2 + (p[1]-ay)**2)
abx, aby = bx - ax, by - ay
ab2 = abx**2 + aby**2
def dist2(p):
    t = ((p[0] - ax)*abx + (p[1] - ay)*aby) / ab2
    xx = ax + t*abx
    yy = ay + t*aby
    return (p[0]-xx)**2 + (p[1]-yy)**2
score = sum(dist2(p) for p in gg)
if best is None or score < best[0]:
    best = score, gg # lower wins
```

Instead of just the line passing from extremes the correct thing would be to find the line with minimum score but that's a bit annoying to compute exactly and this very simple method may be is enough for your use cases

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in your slopes.

Consider as a more extreme example just 3 points. If they are all on a horizontal line, all is well; you compute a slope of zero and this is the best you can get. If you rotate this by 90°, they will all be on a vertical line; their X-coordinates will be exactly equal, and you'll obtain slopes of +inf. The difference inf - inf is nan.

What's happening here is similar: When the line is horizontal, the slopes are < 1; the differences are accordingly relatively small. If you rotate this by 80°, the same line becomes very steep; the slopes will be >> 1; a small difference will increase significantly. Even a worse horizontal line thus achieves a better collinearity rating by your function, simply because the slopes will be < 1.

You need a measure for the collinearity which is invariant under rotations. This is unfortunately not as easy as it seems. One option is to define it as the minimum sum of distances of a set of points after projecting the set of points onto any line (credits for giving me this idea go to my brother). This can probably be more efficiently computed if formulated as an optimization problem, but this naive algorithm just checks 100 possible angles to find the minimum sum of the distances of the points to a line using the given angle as direction.

```py
def mean(nums):
    return sum(nums) / len(nums)

def dot_product(xs, ys):
    return sum(map(lambda tup: tup[0] * tup[1], zip(xs, ys)))

def transpose(points):
    return [p[0] for p in points], [p[1] for p in points]

def coll_coeff(points):
    xs, ys = transpose(points)
    xm, ym = mean(xs), mean(ys)
    xs_centered, ys_centered = [x - xm for x in xs], [y - ym for y in ys]
    def proj(angle):
        direction = (math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle))
        res = 0
        for p in zip(xs_centered, ys_centered):
            plen = math.hypot(p[0], p[1])
            if plen > 0:
                parallel = abs(dot_product(p, direction)) / plen
                ortho = ((1 - parallel) * p[0], (1 - parallel) * p[1])
                res += math.hypot(ortho[0], ortho[1])
        return res
    n = 100 # how many angles to try for the direction of the line
    # we only have to try half the circle
    angles = map(lambda i: math.pi*i/n, range(n))
    return min(map(proj, angles))
```

We can verify that this mostly keeps the coefficients invariant under rotations by picking a couple points and rotating them by 0 to 9 radians:

```py
def rotate(p, rot_angle):
    x, y = p
    length = math.hypot(x, y)
    angle = math.atan2(y, x) + rot_angle
    return length * math.cos(angle), length * math.sin(angle)

test_points = [(688.5, 586.5), (556.5, 448.5), (819.5, 779.5), (453.5, 279.5), (558.5, 585.5)]
for i in range(10):
    rot_points = [rotate(p, i) for p in test_points]
    print(coll_coeff(rot_points))
```

This prints numbers very close to `73.8` ten times. Finally, let's visualize it nicely using matplotlib:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_most_collinear(plot, points):
    xs, ys = transpose(points)
    plot.scatter(xs, ys, c="red")
    most_co_points = find_most_collinear(points)
    xs, ys = transpose(most_co_points)
    plot.scatter(xs, ys, c="blue")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
    plot_most_collinear(axs[0], points_0deg)
    plot_most_collinear(axs[1], points_80deg)
    plt.show()
```

[image: Points visualized using matplotlib]

Comment: That absolutely makes sense. Since the answer of 6502 seems to compute much faster I accepted his answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this using **OpenCV** [HoughLinesWithAccumulator()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/d75/namespacecv.html#a1d6b9c3e48ec579faff9d838cba08e94). I created a black 1000x1000 image and plotted solid white circles at your coordinates. Then I ran the HoughLines() routine to get the best lines - i.e. the ones with the most votes in Hough space.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import math

points_0deg = [[818.5, 395.5], [688.5, 586.5], [556.5, 448.5], [819.5, 779.5], [657.5, 892.5], [558.5, 727.5],
               [658.5, 278.5], [453.5, 279.5], [426.5, 588.5], [877.5, 589.5], [458.5, 893.5], [301.5, 403.5],
               [296.5, 774.5], [241.5, 583.5], [558.5, 585.5]]

points_80deg = [[498.5, 397.5], [665.5, 558.5], [505.5, 665.5], [356.5, 533.5], [781.5, 711.5], [876.5, 463.5],
                [958.5, 641.5], [619.5, 816.5], [700.5, 373.5], [925.5, 838.5], [414.5, 906.5], [322.5, 737.5],
                [580.5, 998.5], [776.5, 975.5], [640.5, 687.5]]

points = points_80deg
# Plot the points as white circles on a 1000x1000 black image
radius = 5
im = np.zeros((1000,1000), np.uint8)
for x,y in points:
    cv.circle(im, (int(x),int(y)), radius, (255,255,255), -1)
cv.imwrite('diagram.png', im)

# Do the Hough Transform
lines = cv.HoughLinesWithAccumulator(im,1,np.pi/180,20)
for n in range(3):
   rho, theta, votes = lines[n][0]
   print(f'lines[{n}]: rho:{rho}, theta:{math.degrees(theta)}, votes:{votes}')
```

The diagram comes out inverted like this because image processing algorithms generally treat top-left corner as origin:

[image]

Using `points_0deg`, I get:

```
lines[0]: rho:586.0, theta:90.00000250447816, votes:47.0
lines[1]: rho:577.0, theta:90.99999684048139, votes:44.0
lines[2]: rho:710.0, theta:18.000000500895634, votes:32.0
```

And using `points_80deg`, I get:

```
lines[0]: rho:760.0, theta:11.000000021511672, votes:45.0
lines[1]: rho:752.0, theta:9.99999970909292, votes:38.0
lines[2]: rho:939.0, theta:45.999999003336896, votes:37.0
```

Comment: Is there also a mathematical solution to this problem? It wouldn't be my first choice to draw the points and then use image processing to find the points.

Comment: I can understand that. Let's wait and see if someone turns up with a better idea.